# Can you handle message extensions with "BotBuilderCloudAdapter.ConversationBot"?

Tags: teams-toolkit

I'm currently using the `ConversationBot` from `BotBuilderCloudAdapter` to handle commands and notifications as the [samples/guides](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-gs-notificationbot?tabs=vscode) suggest. However, I need to add message extension capabilities but can't find a way to do it with that bot.

Based on [this sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/tree/v1.1.0/query-org-user-with-message-extension-sso) I've created a new bot and am running it within my "/api/messages" endpoint like so:

```
server.post("/api/messages", async (req, res) => {
  await conversationBot.requestHandler(req, res, async (context) => {
    await messageExtensionBot.run(context);
  });
});
```

This works but it feels wrong having to run two bots. I'd thought the ConversationBot would handle message extensions?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the `ConversationBot` doesn't support ME related capabilities yet. You can add more capabilities which is not currently handled by the `Conversationbot` by following the steps:

1. Add a `TeamsActivityHandler` to handle the capabilities you need (e.g. message extensions)

```js
const { TeamsActivityHandler } = require("botbuilder");

// An empty teams activity handler.
// You can add your customization code here to extend your bot logic if needed.
class TeamsHandler extends TeamsActivityHandler {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

module.exports.TeamsHandler = TeamsHandler;
```

2. Update your message handler in `index.js` to integrate with your bot:

```js
// Bot Framework message handler.
const teamsHandler = new TeamsHandler();
server.post("/api/messages", async (req, res) => {
  await bot.requestHandler(req, res, async (context) => {
    await teamsHandler.run(context);
  });
});
```

Since you only have one bot runtime (the adapter) in your app, so there will be only one bot instance running for your app. You can think of the `teamsHandler` is extra handler in addition to the `ConversationBot`.

The `ConversationBot` should ideally support additional capabilities without requiring the developer to add extra handlers using the raw bot-builder SDK. We're also actively looking for application scenarios where the TeamsFx SDK can be used to simplify the bot development. Your feedback is really useful for us. Thank you!